# Search and Filter data in ObservableCollection with ICollectionview

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, icollectionview

I use `ICollectionView` to search in the `ObservableCollection` The program works well and I can do the search operation

```
public ICollectionView ItemsView => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataList);
ItemsView.Filter = o => Filter(o as PackageModel);

private bool Filter(PackageModel item)
        {
            return SearchText == null
                       || item.Name.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
                       || item.Publisher.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;

        }
```

Now I want to filter data in the datagrid For example, items with `IsInstalled = true`

```
public bool IsShowOnlyInstalledApps
        {
            get => _isShowOnlyInstalledApps;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isShowOnlyInstalledApps, value);
                if (value)
                {
                    var filter = new Predicate<object>(item => ((PackageModel)item).IsInstalled);
                    ItemsView.Filter = filter;
                }
                else
                {
                    ItemsView.Filter = null;
                }
            } 
        }
```

I can see that the items in the datagrid are filtered But the search operation no longer works

Comment: I think you will need to incorporate both filters by setting event handlers for the filter event.  See this [Multiple Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961268/how-do-you-apply-multiple-filter-functions-on-one-collection-view-source-one-af) and this [How to filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
return SearchText == null
                       || (item.Name.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
                       || (item.Publisher.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
```